# Conditional Windows administrator prompt

Tags: c++, windows, uac, windows-firewall

I'm writing a C++ DLL to connect to a MySQL database.  Among other things, it tries to add an exception to the Windows firewall list so it can connect to the remote MySQL server via TCP (port 3306). When I try to add the port, I get an `HRESULT` of `E_ACCESSDENIED`, unless I run the program as an administrator.

I would like to prompt the user for an administrator password, but only when the port is not already in the exception list.  This means that I can't just create a [UAC manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx), since setting `level="requireAdministrator"` would always prompt for an administrator password, as far as I can tell.  Can I conditionally bring up an administrator prompt?

Comment: You should handle this in your installation rather than the program itself.

Comment: @Wug I'm just writing a DLL, not a full-fledged executable, so there's no installer.

Comment: Maybe there should be one.  Is this dll going to be installed as part of another program?  That program will probably run an installer, and may require administrative rights.  You could add a function in your DLL which performs the firewall setup and hit it from the application installer.

Comment: @1" Then the correct way to do it is to let your DLL's users handle this. It should not be your problem. Otherwise, you can split your program in two: the DLL without manifest, and a `.exe` with a manifest that your DLL runs only when needed.

Comment: What are you writing this DLL for anyway? who's your market/target/audience?

Comment: @syam I'd like to accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: @1'' Just out of curiosity, which advice will you use in the end? Deferring responsibility to your users, or the separate process stuff?

Comment: @syam I'm going to write a separate executable with a manifest and give it to the users.  They can invoke it automatically or manually, since it only has to be used once.  Thanks again for your astute analysis.

Comment: @1" You're welcome, glad to help when I can. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your request, I'm making an answer out of my comment.

---

The correct way to do this is to let your DLL's users handle the situation themselves. As an API developer it is definitely **not** your job to bother about things like a firewall: either the API user and/or end-user made sure it works, or you fail gracefully. As others have said, there are many reasons why the end-user couldn't be able to answer an UAC request (eg. on a headless server) so you mustn't rely on your DLL being used in an interactive context. It's simply not your responsibility.

---

If you *really* must go on with your original idea (which, I stress again, is a bad idea IMHO) my best bet would be to split your DLL in two:

- The DLL itself, without any manifest so it can run under any user,
- and a separate `.exe` with a manifest that requires admin privileges, that will be run by your DLL only when need arises.

Just make it a requirement that both are stored in the same directory so you can easily find your DLL's (and thus the `.exe`'s) directory with `GetModuleFileName`.

Others have pointed out `runas` or `RunDll` (which are equally valid answers IMO) but I'm more of a Unix-y type hence my suggestion of a separate binary altogether. I find it much easier to maintain in the long run.

---

A solution "in-between" would be that your DLL doesn't bother with the firewall at all (as it should) but you provide a completely separate tool (`.exe` with manifest) that helps your users setup the firewall correctly when they need to. This may be the best solution: clean design (separation of responsibility) and still you provide all the required tools to the users.

Comment: I entirely disagree with the statement that developers shouldn't handle firewall settings.  If a piece of software requires a firewall exception, it should create it.  This is a common practice in real-world applications.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, Just because it may be *common* practice in *some* product categories (ie. consumer programs that are don't care about fitting into enterprise environments) doesn't mean it's *good* practice. As developers, we should never forget that the users' machines are under their (or the network admins') *exclusive* control, not ours. But I'll admit, it's always kinda fun to watch an admin go postal on the developers of a badly behaved program... (if you're not the one on the wrong end of the stick, that is)

Comment: As it happens, I'm an enterprise sysadmin, and I prefer software to create the exceptions it needs to function.  If I didn't want them to do this, I would just disable locally created exceptions via group policy - but then I'd have to figure out what the exceptions are and feed them in manually for each application.  That's extra work I don't need.  For the typical end user this is even worse, because it means they'll need assistance to get the program working.  Applications should ask first, which unfortunately many don't, but they shouldn't just leave it to the user to work out what's wrong.

Comment: Related: I do prefer to have a proper installer to software that installs when first run.  However, this isn't always feasible for plugins, as you have to follow the conventions of the parent software.  In such a case, having a separate installer tool which can be either run manually or automatically on first run does sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to elevate the privileges of an application once it is started. In your case, one work around is to use [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx) to launch a small external application with elevated privileges and add the firewall exception there. Once the exception has been added, do whatever cleanup is necessary and exit. You can then wait for the application to finish before you continue execution.

---

Much Kudos to [Cody Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) for pointing out [why RunDll should not be used](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/04/10382242.aspx) and the additional [blog entry by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx) containing more information about issues with `RunDll`

Comment: I don't recommend that; [you should not use RunDll32](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/04/10382242.aspx). Furthermore, the only way that will work is if the DLL has been explicitly written to work with RunDll32. The function signature has to match exactly, otherwise you risk corrupting the stack. This is not only [documented in a KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787), but it's something [Raymond Chen has blogged about](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx).

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for pointing that out. I was unaware it had been deprecated. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Another option would be to use COM, as Raymond recommends.  I believe there is a way for for a COM object to elevate, although I don't recall the details.

Answer (score 1):

You can relaunch your program using ShellExecuteEx with "runas" verb whenever you get E_ACCESSDENIED. Something like this

```
        wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH];
        if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath)))
        {`enter code here`
            // Launch itself as administrator.
            SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = { sizeof(sei) };
            sei.lpVerb = L"runas";
            sei.lpFile = szPath;
            sei.lpParameters=L"admin";
            sei.nShow = SW_NORMAL;

            if (!ShellExecuteEx(&sei))
            {
                DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
                if (dwError == ERROR_CANCELLED)
                {
                    ExitProcess(0);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ExitProcess(0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is very bad behavior in a piece of software.  Unless the software needs administrative privileges on a continuous basis to run (in which case it should never ask for them, but always require them), it should never ask.  You wouldn't be able to use this DLL in any system that needs to run without user input, since a change in firewall configuration might make it ask for permission and never run.

Comment: lol ya beat me to it. Feel free to merge the info about `RunDll` into your answer as it applies directly to what the OP needs to do.

Comment: Isn't this fine if the DLL only needs to do this once, and a user will always be at the computer when it is invoked?

Comment: What if they're not at the computer when it's invoked? what if someone uses your plugin on a server remotely with no GUI access? where does the runas prompt go?  If plugins are given administrative access willy nilly, what's to stop me from writing a plugin that patches the kernel and installs a rootkit?  It's a much better idea to set it up once, at install time.  It will never require administrative privileges at runtime if you do that.

Comment: @Wug: in practice, most software cannot be meaningfully used in a non-interactive context.  Unless the software the user's plugin is meant for is naturally non-interactive, there's no reason for the plugin not to present an elevation prompt.